# At what altitude after takeoff is thrust reduced for airliners?

Tags: jet-engine, takeoff, climb

When is thrust, after take off reduced for jumbos and smaller airliners?

Is it any different for jumbos and smaller airliner aircraft?

Comment: Or 5 minutes after initiating maximum thrust.